# Getting Cards to Sort to Top Left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a card layout here: http://jesseddy.com/resource-library. I'm using a jQuery plugin called Tagsort (https://wch.io/projects/tagsort) to filter the cards based on tags. Functionally it works but visually the cards are meant to stack on the top when filtered, that specific bit is not working.

To see it how it's meant to work see this: https://wch.io/static/tagsort/demo-stacks/index.html

Use mine to see it not working: http://jesseddy.com/resource-library (filter using more than one tag).

I think I've identified the issue is that I am using list items in my layout but I am not sure how to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery plugin only applies the `display: none` style to `div.item` because  you initialized the plugin as such `$('div.tags-container').tagSort({items: '.item', ... })` and only the DOM elements with the class `item` will be toggled. In your current version, the `<li>` elements are still present and take up space although the inner elements have been set to `display: none`.

You will have to change your markup and shift the class `item` and attribute `data-item-tags` to the `<li>` instead of the inner `div`.

Comment: Yang, that worked like a charm, thank you!! It's created one more issue, I have a bit of padding inside the left hand side of the card, which I can't for the life of me figure out where it's coming from or how to properly align. Thanks for your help!